# Web Data scraping: getting all data by selecting drop down menus python

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, drop-down-menu

I am trying to get data from [https://www.iplt20.com/teams/sunrisers-hyderabad/squad"](https://www.iplt20.com/teams/sunrisers-hyderabad/squad%22)
but facing one issue particularly with drop down list("**filter by year**").

i was able to retrieve names in drop down list i.e. 2020,2019,. etc
but cannot retrieve data for each list element.

when we click on **filter by year** list, a drop down list appears and then on season(year), player changes(we get players who played that years season along with summary).
i want to get data for each player by season.
Also no new URL is created when we click on drop down list

I am not able to find any solution for it.
using following python code to retrieve season/year values from drop down list.

**Python code**

```
    squad_url= "https://www.iplt20.com/teams/sunrisers-hyderabad/squad"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=".\chromedriver.exe")
    driver.get(squad_url)
    html = driver.page_source
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(''.join(html), 'html.parser')
    for llist in soup2.find_all("ul",class_="drop-down__dropdown-list"):
        for year in llist.find_all("li"):
            print(year.text)
```

**snippet of html code for drop down list is below**

```
<div class="large-squad-list__filter single-filter">
        <div class="stats-table__filter drop-down js-drop-down is-open">
            <div class="drop-down__clickzone js-dropdown-trigger" tabindex="0" role="button"></div>
            <div class="drop-down__label js-drop-down-label">Filter by Year</div>
            <div class="drop-down__current js-drop-down-current">2020</div>
            <ul class="drop-down__dropdown-list js-drop-down-options">
                <li tabindex="0" role="button" class="drop-down__dropdown-list__option" data-option="ipl2020">2020</li>
                <li tabindex="0" role="button" class="drop-down__dropdown-list__option" data-option="ipl2019">2019</li>
                <li tabindex="0" role="button" class="drop-down__dropdown-list__option" data-option="ipl2018">2018</li>
                <li tabindex="0" role="button" class="drop-down__dropdown-list__option" data-option="ipl2017">2017</li>
                <li tabindex="0" role="button" class="drop-down__dropdown-list__option" data-option="ipl2016">2016</li>
                <li tabindex="0" role="button" class="drop-down__dropdown-list__option" data-option="ipl2015">2015</li>
                <li tabindex="0" role="button" class="drop-down__dropdown-list__option" data-option="ipl2014">2014</li>
                <li tabindex="0" role="button" class="drop-down__dropdown-list__option" data-option="ipl2013">2013</li>
                <li tabindex="0" role="button" class="drop-down__dropdown-list__option" data-option="ipl2012">2012</li>
                <li tabindex="0" role="button" class="drop-down__dropdown-list__option" data-option="ipl2011">2011</li>
                <li tabindex="0" role="button" class="drop-down__dropdown-list__option" data-option="ipl2010">2010</li>
                <li tabindex="0" role="button" class="drop-down__dropdown-list__option" data-option="ipl2009">2009</li>
                <li tabindex="0" role="button" class="drop-down__dropdown-list__option" data-option="ipl2008">2008</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You're scraping `iplt20` yet list as `ipl2020` (no `t`), is that on purpose?

Comment: yes , i have posted only part of my code, in my actual code i can pass down which year's/season's(2020,2019 etc) data i want .naming convention are also aligned with season year to maintain uniformity and readability , that's why i prefer it this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After full days hard work, i was able to do it:

**Import following  in code**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException
```

**Python Code Below**

```
    driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element)
    
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, -100);")
    time.sleep(2)
    #above code ensures drop list is visible, otherwise we get errors of non clickable etc.

    element = driver.find_element_by_class_name("stats-table__filter")
    season_element = element.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")
    for season in season_element:
        action.move_to_element_with_offset(element,0,0).perform()
        element.click()
        action.move_to_element_with_offset(season,0,0).perform()
        time.sleep(2) 

        try:
            print("clicking:",season.text )
            season.click()
        except WebDriverException:
            print("Not clickable", season.text)
            break
```

Above logic only contains info of how to click on drop down list.
but with it dynamic data is getting loaded(i have confirmed from driver.page_source output)

issue with **requests** library is dynamic data was not getting loaded.
but with selenium one can easily do it.

I have added sleeps to make sure scrolling is completed.
i read at a lot of places instead of sleep can use **WebDriverWait**, but i was not able to make them work

I am pretty much sure there can be optimised version.
(please post here if find one)

Answer (score 0):

This might by only a partial answer, but it does get what you're going for (the stats).

The problem is, that the data is loaded dynamically by JS. However, if you take a look at the traffic (check Developer Tool -> Network) you'll see thare's a request sent to an API.

You can grab that url and parse the response.

This is exactly what the code does:

```
import requests


_ids = [18790, 10192, 7749, 5815, 3957, 2785, 2374, 605]


for _id in _ids:
    url = f"https://cricketapi.platform.iplt20.com/stats/" \
          f"players?teamIds=62&tournamentIds={_id}&scope=TOURNAMENT&pageSize=30"
    response = requests.get(url).json()
    print(f"Printing stats for {response['team']['fullName']}")
    for player in response['stats']['content']:
        print(f"{player['player']['fullName']} - {player['stats']}")
```

However, I was not able to pin down where the `tournamentIds` come from. Also, there's no data past year 2013.

Sample output (only part of it, for brevity):

```
Printing stats for Sunrisers Hyderabad
Yusuf Pathan - [{'matchType': 'AGG', 'battingStats': {'50s': 0, '100s': 0, 'inns': 8, 'm': 10, 'r': '40', 'b': 45, '4s': 1, '6s': 1, 'no': 5, 'hs': '16*', 'sr': '88.88', 'a': '13.33'}, 'bowlingStats': {'bbiw': 0, 'bbir': 0, 'bbmw': 0, 'bbmr': 0, '4w': 0, '5w': 0, '10w': 0, 'inns': 1, 'm': 10, 'b': 6, 'r': 8, 'wb': 0, 'nb': 0, 'd': 1, 'w': 0, '4s': 1, '6s': 0, 'maid': 0, 'wmaid': 0, 'ht': 0, 'a': '-', 'e': '8.00', 'sr': '-', 'o': '1.00'}, 'fieldingStats': {'c': 1, 'ro': 0, 's': 0, 'inns': 1, 'm': 10}}, {'matchType': 'IPLT20', 'battingStats': {'50s': 0, '100s': 0, 'inns': 8, 'm': 10, 'r': '40', 'b': 45, '4s': 1, '6s': 1, 'no': 5, 'hs': '16*', 'sr': '88.88', 'a': '13.33'}, 'bowlingStats': {'bbiw': 0, 'bbir': 0, 'bbmw': 0, 'bbmr': 0, '4w': 0, '5w': 0, '10w': 0, 'inns': 1, 'm': 10, 'b': 6, 'r': 8, 'wb': 0, 'nb': 0, 'd': 1, 'w': 0, '4s': 1, '6s': 0, 'maid': 0, 'wmaid': 0, 'ht': 0, 'a': '-', 'e': '8.00', 'sr': '-', 'o': '1.00'}, 'fieldingStats': {'c': 1, 'ro': 0, 's': 0, 'inns': 1, 'm': 10}},
```

Comment: yes, after looking around on internet i found that selenium  is the answer to fix this problem :)